# Focus in vs Focus on

Tags: prepositions

Should I say **focus in** or **focus on**.
In which situations is better to use one over the other.

> I need to focus *on/in* quality issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the preposition "on", not "in", after the verb "focus" when you give a lot of or particular attention to somebody or something,

So the correct sentence is:

I need to focus on quality issues.

Comment: Yes, focus on,but people also say: to focus in on something.